# Finding the slope of the other median of a right triangle?

Tags: geometry

> Q) It is desired to construct a right triangle $ABC$  $(C=\pi/2) $ in the coordinate plane
>   so that its legs are parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes and so that the
>   medians through A and B lie on the lines $y = 3x + 1$ and
>   $y = mx + 2$. The number of different constants $m$ for which such a
>   triangle exists is/are ?

I was able to identify a case where $m<3$ will only make a median but when i tried drawing a few more that was flawed .
How do i begin an approach ?

Comment: Check your question. Both medians through A and B should have negative slope if .the triangle's legs are parallel to the x and y axes.

Comment: @Aniket yes but aren't there cases where slopes need not be negative ?

Comment: Can you explain by a diagram?

Comment: @Aniket a possible case (i think) http://i.stack.imgur.com/CG5hy.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A(s,3s+1),B(t,mt+2)$ where $m\not=3$.

Now let us separate it into cases.

Case 1 : $C(t,3s+1)$

Since the midpoint of the side $AC$ is on the line $y=mt+2$,
$$3s+1=m\cdot\frac{s+t}{2}+2\iff (6-m)s-mt=2\tag1$$
Also, since the midpoint of the side $BC$ is on the line $y=3x+1$,
$$\frac{3s+1+mt+2}{2}=3t+1\iff 3s+(m-6)t=-1\tag2$$
Eliminating $s$ from $(1)(2)$ gives
$$(m-12)(m-3)t=12-m$$
Here, if $m\not=12$, then $s=t=\frac{1}{3-m}$, which is a contradiction.

So, in this case, the only possible $m$ is $m=12$. (it's easy to see that this is sufficient)

Case 2 : $C(s,mt+2)$

We have the followings :
$$\frac{3s+1+mt+2}{2}=m\cdot s+2\iff (3-2m)s+mt=1\tag3$$
$$mt+2=3\frac{t+s}{2}+1\iff 3s+(3-2m)t=2\tag 4$$

Eliminating $s$ from $(3)(4)$ gives
$$(4m-3)(m-3)t=-(4m-3)$$
If $4m-3\not=0$, then $t=s=\frac{1}{3-m}$, which is a contradiction.

So, in this case, the only possible $m$ is $m=3/4$.

Hence, the number of different constants $m$ for which such a triangle exists is $\color{red}{2}$.